# get position fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to display detailed data from the dasboardFragment to the dasboardDetailFragment. according to its position with listView.setOnItemClickListener

dashboardFragment.java

```
public class dashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView lv;

    SearchView searchView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] menuItem ={"Panti Asuhan Arif Rahman Hakim",
            "Panti Asuhan Undaan Surabaya",
            "Panti Asuhan Yatim Piatu Al Mu'Min",
            "Panti Asuhan At Taqwa",
            "Panti Asuhan Al-Fatih",
            "Panti Asuhan Al Kahfi",
            "Panti Asuhan BJ Habibie",
            "Panti Asuhan KH. AR. FAKHRUDDIN",
            "Panti Asuhan Karya Asih",
            "Panti Asuhan Ibnu Sina Kertajaya",
            "Panti Asuhan Yatim Cahaya Insani",
            "Griya Yatim & Dhuafa surabaya",
            "Panti Asuhan Wachid Hasyim",
            "Panti Asuhan Al-Hikmah Muhammadiyah",
            "Panti Asuhan Amanah",
            "Yayasan Panti Asuhan Sabilillah",
            "Rumah Anak Pondok Kasih",
            "Panti Asuhan Lydia",
            "Panti Asuhan Yatim Aisyiyah",
            "Panti Asuhan Al Jabbar "};
    private ArrayList<String> ada;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuItem);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                FragmentTransaction fr= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new dasboardDetailFragment());
                fr.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;

    }
}
```

dasboardDetailFragment.java

```
public class dasboardDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public dasboardDetailFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    private TextView Getnama, Getjam, GetAlamat;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dasboard_detail, container, false);


    }

}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below on your setOnItemClickListener

```
                Gson mGson = new Gson();
                Datum cars = mData.get(position); // grabbing the cars list from another object
                String carsListString = mGson.toJson(cars);
                dasboardDetailFragment myTripDetailFragment = new dasboardDetailFragment();
                Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
                mBundle.putString(AppConstants.DATA, carsListString);
                myTripDetailFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
                FragmentTransaction fr= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fr.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myTripDetailFragment);
                fr.commit();
```

In Details Fragment below code

```
        Gson mGson = new Gson();
        String  mImagesList = getArguments().getString(AppConstants.DATA);
        String mTlogsList = mGson.fromJson(mImagesList, new TypeToken<String>(){}.getType());
```

From mTloglist you can get the data!